# How can I use commands to give an item to the person who killed a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For example, if player A killed player B, how can I make it so player A gets a specific item using commands? ~~~{if you killed A player you will get diamond,if you kill B player you will get emerald for example

I tried these commands but it gives all player the same item + I want a specific player is killed

Commands:
To get a command block -

```
/give USERNAME minecraft:command_block
```

To create the first scoreboard -

```
/scoreboard objectives add Kills playerKillCount
```

To create the second scoreboard -

```
/scoreboard objectives add Count playerKillCount
```

To add the first scoreboard to the side bar -

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Kills
```

First command block:
For diamonds -

```
/give @p[scores={Count=1..]} minecraft:diamond 1
```

For emeralds -

```
/give @p[scores={Count=1..]} minecraft:emerald 1
```

For XP -

```
/xp add @p[scores={Count=1..]} 1 levels
```

Second command block:

```
/scoreboard players reset @p[Scores={Count=1..]} Count
```

To clear kill sidebar:

```
/scoreboard players reset @a Kills
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you've at least tried to help yourself—have you tried looking for solutions but didn't find anything? Please share what you found and why it didn't do what you wanted. You also need to add a tag to your question to specify what version you're playing, either `minecraft-java-edition`, `minecraft-bedrock-edition`, or one of the other MC edition tags. Commands are very different when you switch editions, so please [edit] your question to include your Minecraft edition and what research you've done.

Comment: thx for your help + I edited the question

Comment: Can you use a data pack?

Comment: I answered a similar question it might help you: 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380860/minecraft-scoreboards-how-do-i-track-how-many-times-a-player-kills-another-spec/383627#383627

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Semlan Bakelsen's comment.